# How RouterLink and RouterLinkActive work?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Consider the following example:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>
```

The active-link CSS class will be added to the a tag when the current URL is either "/user" or "/user/bob",

How could I enforce an exact match?

Comment: What do you want to make it work?

Comment: I want to apply the css when the active route is a child route.

Comment: If you apply the active route on the child component the parent component doesn't change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to full match the url. You can add the `routerLinkActiveOptions`.

e.g.

```
<a [routerLink]="/user" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Bob</a>
```

Then only when the url is '/user' will add class. The '/user/bob' will not.