# Angular RouterLink Issue

Tags: angular, routerlink, routerlinkactive

Object:
I have a menu with a searchBarInput
on InputValueChange

=> update the url by adding a key search with the input value

=> it work well but by doing that I destroyed the sidebar routerLinkActive system.

why ? and how to resolve it?

Html

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (ngModelChange)="onSearchQueryChange()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
// sidebar.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { QueryParamService } from './query-param.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent {
  searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(private queryParamService: QueryParamService) {}

  onSearchQueryChange() {
    // Create a JSON object with the search query parameter
    const queryParams = { search: this.searchQuery };

    // Call the service to update the query parameters
    this.queryParamService.updateQueryParams(queryParams);
  }
}
```

Service

```
// query-param.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QueryParamService {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  updateQueryParams(queryParams: { [key: string]: string | number }) {
    const currentQueryParams = { ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams };
    const updatedQueryParams = { ...currentQueryParams, ...queryParams };

    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: updatedQueryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
  }
}
```

the routerLink is not updating on link change

The components are switching

Comment: Are you facing any error? pls check the console window and let me know if it's showing any error.

Comment: no error nothing, without the router.navigate the routerActiveLink work but the queryParam search ofc doesn't go inside the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why?

It's because your routes don't match anymore.  When you append your search parameter to the url, the route no longer matches.

and how to resolve it?

The documentation goes over this:
https://angular.io/guide/routing-with-urlmatcher and
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Basically you need to set a routerLinkOptions property.  A decent example can be found here: [How RouterLink and RouterLinkActive work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863797/how-routerlink-and-routerlinkactive-work).

Comment: so as I understand I should do this `<a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">Home</a>`
 but it doesn't work to. Btw the value false is the default value if I'm not wrong. And is the route route realy changing ? because the route is still '/home' but with a queryParam '/home?search=helloWorld'

Comment: You should probably post your route table then.

Comment: I made a prototype and the code is working well, the issue is some where else in the project. I have to investigate. Thanks for your help